# How to extract error code from a JSON error message

Tags: javascript, json

Error message is showing like below.

```
"{\"errorCode\":\"2029\",\"errorMessage\":\"Duplicate Entry\"}"
```

How do I extract errorCode from above in javascript?

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the error message to an object and then select the errorCode:

```js
const errorMessage = "{\"errorCode\":\"2029\",\"errorMessage\":\"Duplicate Entry\"}";
const errorMessageObject = JSON.parse(errorMessage);
const errorCode = errorMessageObject.errorCode;

console.log(errorCode)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a JSON encoded object. In order to access the properties of the encoded object, you need to json decode it first. You can use `JSON.parse()`.
Then you can get its properties simply by property name.

Eg:

```
let encodedString = "{\"errorCode\":\"2029\",\"errorMessage\":\"Duplicate Entry\"}";
let decodedObj = JSON.parse(encodedString);

console.log(decodedObj.errorCode); // prints "2029"
```

You can use `parseInt()` to extract the error code as a number rather than a string.
Eg:

```
console.log(parseInt(decodedData.errorCode)); // prints 2029
```

Comment: Please note that JSON isn't always an encoded object. `1` is valid JSON, so is `"Hello"`.